# What's the meaning of the operator || in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I found this piece of code in a .sh script:

```
 (test -x "$1" || which "$1")
```

What does this operator `||` mean?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's equivalent to boolean "or" with short-circuiting evaluation, such that it will execute the second command only if the first returns some value corresponding to "false".  For example:

```
false || echo "foo"
```

echoes "foo", while

```
true || echo "foo"
```

Prints nothing.  The `&&` operator provides a complimentary operation.

Comment: What does `complimentary operation` mean here?

Comment: @niaomingjian That I embarrassingly typo'd complementary. I meant that short-circuiting logical "and" is the complement of logical "or" when considering possible ways of combining commands.

Answer (score 8):

it means:

if the first command succeed the second will never be executed

Answer (score 1):

What the double pipe does is execute the first command, if it succeeds then it stops execution, if no the second one will be executed.

It's the opposite of &&.